# How to merge JSON in while loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a while loop for getting JSON response from API. Here is my code.

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets?sort_by=created_at"

payload = ""
headers = {
    'Authorization': "Basic blablabla"
    }
params="page[size]=3"

while url:
    response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=params)
    data = response.json()

    #get only tickets array and drop everything else
    dataTickets = json.dumps(data['tickets'],indent=2)
    #print(dataTickets)

    #get next page of data
    url = data['links']['next']
```

Each loop gives me the following.

```
[
    {'url': 'https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4025.json'},
    {'url': 'https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4026.json'},
    {'url': 'https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4027.json'}
]
```

**How to merge each loop run (inside the loop) to get merged array as follows:**

```
[
    {'url': 'https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4025.json'},
    {'url': 'https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4026.json'},
    {'url': 'https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4027.json'},
    {'url': 'https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4028.json'},
    {'url': 'https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4029.json'},
    {'url': 'https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4030.json'},
    {'url': 'https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4031.json'},
    {'url': 'https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4032.json'},
    {'url': 'https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/4033.json'}
]
```

Comment: Just concatenate the lists...

Comment: How about you initialise an empty list `res = []` , and extend into it , `res.extend(url)`

Comment: I have been trying
`res_dict = {"tickets": dataTickets + dataTickets}
to_json = json.dumps(res_dict)`
but that add a lot of /n everywhere in the JSON.

Comment: It looks like i have to reload the list with json.loads after json.dump

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. I went about it slightly differently.

1. I am processing the full request where I merge the "tickets" array.
2. After I merge it, I take just the "tickets" out and print it. This helps me to manipulate just the tickets later.

The data in one request loop looks as follows:

```
{
  "tickets": [
    {
      "url": "https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/3058.json"
    },
    {
      "url": "https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/3059.json"
    }
  ],
  "next_page": "https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json?page=2",
  "previous_page": null,
  "count": 3234
}
```

```
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://org.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets?sort_by=created_at"

payload = ""
headers = {
    'Authorization': "Basic blablabla"
    }
params="page[size]=3"

while url:
    response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=params)
    data = response.json()

    #merge (extend) tickets array for every loop
    data["tickets"] += data["tickets"]

    #get next page of data
    url = data['links']['next']

# Format the merged JSON and take out just the tickets array
dataout =  json.dumps(data["tickets"],indent=2)

# Write formatted JSON into file
with open('tickets1.json', 'w') as f:
   f.write(dataout)
```